# Property with the same name as the subtype name

Tags: c#, syntax

Is it possible to declare property with the same name as classes subtypes name? Something like this:

```
class WorkerResult 
{
    public enum Status
    {
         Okay,
         Wrong,
         SomethingElse
    };

    public Status Status {get;set;}
    public object Data {get;set;}
}
```

This results into following error:

```
The type 'WorkerResult' already contains a definition for 'Status' File.cs
```

Comment: Why do you need the enum and the property to have the same name?

Comment: @DominicKexel it can be easily swapped to `WorkerStatus`, I was just curious whether it's possible (and whether there's some specific syntax) or no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have subtype with the same name as the property and you will get the conflict.. You can try declaring it outside.

```
public enum Status
{
     Okay,
     Wrong,
     SomethingElse
};

class WorkerResult 
{
    public Status Status {get;set;}
    public object Data {get;set;}
}
```

**Edit**
As @Ashigore commented, you should achieve clarity by renaming it. Having a property as well as an enum adds the confusion. Or worst case if you dont want to rename it, consider having the enum in the same file to show the stronger association rather than having it within the class.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this solution (although `Status` contains very specific values to `WorkerResult` and we wanted to emphasize that).

Comment: @Vyktor In that case you should rename the enum to `WorkerResultStatus`, that is the correct way to emphasize such a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to declare property with the same name as classes
>   subtypes name?

No, it is a basic naming conflict - you are at the same name scope. Think about the code-client of your class, which `Status` will be supplied to him?

```
var worker = new WorkerResult();
var status = worker.Status; //Which one will be supplied??
```

Declare it ***outside*** of the `class` and not as a member within it:

```
public enum Status
{
     Okay,
     Wrong,
     SomethingElse
};

class WorkerResult 
{
    public Status Status {get;set;}
    public object Data {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice question and tricky I would do something like that:

```
public class WorkerResult
{
  public static class Consts
  {
    public enum Status
    {
      Okay,
      Wrong,
      SomethingElse
    };
  }

  public Consts.Status Status { get; set; }
  public object Data { get; set; }
}
```